# What was the first story to feature the plot "the monsters were human all along"?

Tags: history-of, science-fiction-genre, fantasy-genre

The plot/trope where some crime so violent or egregious has happened that some alien/monster is automatically suspected to be behind it, only for our human protagonists to investigate, and in the end find out the culprits were actually humans has been used in a number of shows, e.g:

- *Torchwood* "Countrycide" (2006)
- *Supernatural* "The Benders" (2006)
- *The X-Files* "Home" (1996)

And probably many more.

What was the first work to feature this plot?

---

I'm looking for examples of something like the intersection of these two tropes: [Human All Along](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/HumanAllAlong) (though perceived to be non-human for their violent actions, not their appearance, which is unknown) and [Humans Are The Real Monsters](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/HumansAreTheRealMonsters)

While interesting, examples where it turns out our protagonists (that we thought were human) are aliens, and the antagonists (that we thought were alien) were actually the humans, are not what I'm looking for!

e.g. [*Sentry*](https://archive.org/details/Galaxy_v07n05_1954-02/page/n125), *The Twilight Zone* ["The Invaders"](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/211547/115917)

Comment: The suspected "monsters" are not necessarily space aliens, right? People are suspecting the mischief is done by ghosts or witches or devils, but the villains turn out to be mortal human beings?

Comment: If the monsters are not real, then the story with that plot is not necessarily sci-fi, and therefore not necessarily on topic here?

Comment: @user1411 yep, exactly - they can be perceived to be any sort of non-human 'monster'. I suppose it may not be necessarily, but all examples I've encountered have been episodes within explicitly sci-fi/fantasy series, and I imagine the story would be 'framed' in a sci-fi way up until the big reveal.

Comment: So you're talking about things like Monsters Inc. and Smallfoot?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93187/discussion-on-question-by-ukemi-what-was-the-first-story-to-feature-the-plot-th).

Comment: https://io9.gizmodo.com/10-best-science-fiction-stories-where-humans-are-the-mo-1403055457

Comment: Note to readers: the title of this question [was edited](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/posts/211458/timeline#history_b028c9e2-59fa-4336-8097-5076b9fb13cd) from *"the humans were the monsters all along"* to *"the monsters were human all along"* after several answers had already been posted, and the question text has been significantly changed / clarified as well. Some of the highly upvoted answers below may no longer fit the new wording.

Comment: Additionally, an antecedent I mentioned from the second century BCE got removed because “Religious works aren't considered science fiction here,” but the edited question removes all reference to science fiction, and merely asks for the first work to feature this plot.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[The Legend of Sleepy Hollow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Legend_of_Sleepy_Hollow) (1820), in which Ichabod is frightened by a headless horseman, is a good candidate.

From Wikipedia:

> Although the true nature of both the Headless Horseman and Ichabod's disappearance that night are left open to interpretation, the story implies that the ghost was really Brom (an agile stunt rider) in disguise, and suggests that Crane was knocked off his horse and immediately fled Sleepy Hollow, never to return there again.

Answer (score 43):

[*I Am Legend*](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/40940649-i-am-legend) (1954), by Richard Matheson.

At the end of the novel:

> Neville discovers that the new vampires are terrified of him - he is a boogey-man to them, as he has been murdering their kind in their sleep.

Comment: _A new terror born in death, a new superstition entering the unassailable fortress of forever. I am legend._

Comment: @Jenayah If only they'd had the guts to use that in the Will Smith travesty.

Comment: @Graham I know right... Not necessarily a bad movie, but the ending (even the alternative one) was disappointing :(

Comment: This is missing the "Human All Along" half of the requirement. There's never any doubt that Neville is human.

Comment: This totally isn't an answer to the question...

Comment: @OrangeDog: but Neville isn't known to be the bad guy all along.

Comment: @Martha exactly, another reason why it doesn't fit the question

Comment: @OrangeDog: on the contrary. Throughout the story, we assume that the zombies/vampires are the bad guys... but in the end, it turns out that the REAL bad guy was the one human.

Comment: @Martha which is not what the question is asking for. It's almost the exact opposite.

Comment: -1 the IAL twist is the nature of the actions instead of the identity of the culprits. @OP is looking for a story where 1. evil thing happens, 2. It looks like evil thing was done by a monster, 3. it was a human who did it. *I Am Legend* goes like 1. thing happens but we think it is good, 2. new perspective, 3. the thing in 1. was evil. Maybe they're both "The Monster Was Human All Along." I think a story that answers the question should establish the actions in question were always evil but the identity of the perpetrator of those *same* acts is the twist.

Comment: Why is this getting upvotes?  The vampires were not human all along?

Comment: The vampires were human, or at least decidedly moreso than Neville ever even conceived of before this point. They came from humans and had thoughts, feelings, and terrifying legends of *him*.  What he learned is that they are decidedly capable of living like humans do, are really not monstrous, and he's been murdering them as they sleep because *he* didn't understand them.

Answer (score 16):

I do not know which story was the first, but I do know of a story decades earlier than the examples in the question that made a big impression on me, a short story by Lord Dunsany.

The story is "Mgamu" published in [*The Fourth Book of Jorkens*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?967480) (1948).  A monster called the *sivver-verri* is feared by all the tribes in Kenya, and known only by the carnage it leaves behind in huts that it enters.  It leaves no survivors as witnesses.  No man, woman, or child has ever seen the sivver-verri and lived. "Mgamu" tells the story of the one person who has seen the sivver-verri and lived.

Considering the subject of the question this answers, it may be easy to guess which species the sivver-verri is a member of, but I don't like to give away surprise endings.

---

And the trope [Humans are the Real Monsters](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/HumansAreTheRealMonsters/Literature) should have examples from before 1954 and does have a few including *Gulliver's Travels* (1726) with the Yahoos, & H.G. Wells's *The Island of Doctor Moreau* (1896), if they fit the original question closely enough.

Comment: And how does that story fit the theme? You can put it under spoiler tags.

Answer (score 16):

> This is the woman who lives in the house … a woman about to face
>   terror, which is even now coming at her from - The Twilight Zone.

### [The Invaders - The Twilight Zone S02E15](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Invaders_(The_Twilight_Zone)) (1961)

A woman hears noises and finds a UFO lands on her roof. Small aliens (looking about 6" tall) come into her house and start attacking her. She beats one and throws it into the fire. The other aliens tries to get away and radios a warning to stay away from the planet.

> The camera pans to the markings on the side of the ship, which reads
>   **U.S. Air Force Space Probe No. 1**. The invaders were not tiny, but were
>   **human astronauts from Earth**; the woman in the small farmhouse belongs
>   to a race of giant humanoids native to another planet.

[<sub>Wikipedia - The Invaders - The Twilight Zone S02E15</sub>](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Invaders_(The_Twilight_Zone))

The Invaders were actually astronauts from Earth (doo doo, DOO doo). The lady actually never speaks throughout the episode. Only at the end of the show is the voice warning to stay away and the showing of the U.S. markings on the space craft.

This is not as old as other answers but seems more in the spirit of Monsters Were Human All Along.

There's a [short version on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n99iNW9595o).

Comment: "examples where it turns out our protagonists (that we thought were human) are aliens, and the antagonists (that we thought were alien) were actually the humans, are not what I'm looking for!"

Comment: Isn't there one of those episodes where there's a woman who is treated like an alien at a hospital, but turns out to be human and the surgeons are aliens?

Comment: @RedwolfPrograms - that's probably Eye of the Beholder(
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eye_of_the_Beholder_(1960_Twilight_Zone_episode) ) you're thinking of, but it's just that the woman is good looking and everyone else is normally deformed by our standards. I think they were they same people.

Answer (score 14):

[*Scooby-Doo*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scooby-Doo) (1969) is a good contender.

Most episodes follow exactly the plot you describe:

- Some crime or shenanigans is afoot (though as a kid's cartoon there isn't egregious violence)
- Some monster is assumed to be behind it
- Our human (and canine) protagonists investigate
- In the end we find out the culprits were actually humans

Whether it passes the "through actions, not appearance" test is debatable. I'm not going to check through every episode, but there are probably ones where it's already assumed to be a monster before the inevitable man-sized costume.

Comment: The Three Investigators books (1964 - 1987) are similar where people try to scare others away by pretending to be monsters.

Comment: That's what lept to mind for me too!  I just didn't realise it as was old enough to be a contender for "first"!!

Comment: There are episodes with a different plot?

Answer (score 6):

How about Mary Shelly's Frankenstein. First published in 1818. In the end, who is really the monster?

Comment: For those who haven’t read it could you [edit] this to explain better how it matches?

Comment: I don't think that's an answer to the question asked. While Frankenstein's monster is in part a victim, the humans don't really realise _they_ are the monsters, or that the creature sees them as such (which he doesn't, I think).

Comment: @Jenayah I see where you're coming from, but at various points, Frankenstein himself admits that he finds his own actions monstrous, so it seems like it would stand. Frankenstein's monster initially wishes to make peace will his progenitor, but also eventually comes to hold this opinion, as he pursues his Frankenstein to the latter's death.

Comment: https://twitter.com/josephscrimshaw/status/575157956104204288?lang=en

Comment: I’m sorry but people who say that “Frankenstein was the real monster” clearly haven’t actually read the book. He’s a timid fool, perhaps, and of course Shelley’s Christian upbringing and the morals of her era influences her implication that attempting to create life from scratch is blasphemous hubris. But even she doesn’t conclude that Frankenstein is a monster in any sense of the word. He’s clearly a victim. (It also doesn’t fit trope regardless.)

Comment: @Konrad Rudolph  Victor Frankenstein creates a child and then abandons that child to its fate, violating his legal and ethical parental responsibility to that child.  Thus Frankenstein has often been criticized as being monstrous not for creating the creature but for deserting and abandoning it, and perhaps that was Mary Shelley's intention.

Comment: I think the point of what OP is asking is about monsters being something monstrous that isn't human. So, yes, Frankenstein's monster is most certainly "the monster" in this context.

Comment: @M.A.Golding That's a highly idiosyncratic reading. Even ignoring that the monster isn't really a child (though it certainly has *some* child-like qualities), Frankenstein didn't abandon it out of malice but out of genuine fear. Casting Frankenstein as a monster isn't supported by the source material. It's a postmodern reinterpretation that intentionally ignores the source.

Answer (score 2):

Mary Shelly's Frankenstein is good, but HG Wells' 1896 [The Island of Dr Moreau](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Island_of_Doctor_Moreau) nails it.

From Wikipedia:

> The text of the novel is the narration of Edward Prendick, a
>   shipwrecked man rescued by a passing boat who is left on the island
>   home of Doctor Moreau, a mad scientist who creates human-like hybrid
>   beings from animals via vivisection. The novel deals with a number of
>   philosophical themes, including pain and cruelty, moral
>   responsibility, human identity, and human interference with nature.
>   Wells described it as "an exercise in youthful blasphemy."

and

> Upon his return to England, Prendick is no longer comfortable in the
>   presence of humans, all of whom seem to him to be about to revert to
>   an animal state. He leaves London and lives in near-solitude in the
>   countryside, devoting himself to chemistry as well as astronomy in the
>   studies of which he finds some peace.

Dr. Moreau's end comes when he dies at the hands... paws... of one of the monsters he created when she tried to escape from the pain he was causing her.

Answer (score 2):

[Dr No (1962)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dr._No_(film))

The first James Bond movie villain, Dr. No, has a typical [Supervillain Lair](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/SupervillainLair) (Warning: TV Tropes) in Crab Key guarded by a dragon. Locals residents stay away from the island because of the dragon. Anyone who has gone there hasn't returned.

When Bond goes there to investigate Dr. No, he discovers that the dragon is actually a tank with a flamethrower. Dr. No's henchman use it to keep the secret lair from being discovered.

> After nightfall, they are attacked by the "dragon" of Crab Key, which
>   is in reality a flamethrower-equipped tank.

I think this fits the requirements, though it's a minor plot point in the movie.